# How do I take an input without this happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to Javascript and Node.js and I'm trying to take an input however every time a character is typed the question prints into the console again.

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
 
const name = prompt('What is your name?\n');
console.log(`Hey there ${name}`);
```

Output:

```
What is your name?
What is your name?
What is your name?
What is your name?
kai
Hey there kai
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const name = prompt('What is your name?\n');
```

Try without the `\n` character:

```
var value = 'frank';
var name = prompt('What is your name? ', value);
```

Have a look here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync#examples